# bootstrap-wysihtml5 is not displaying on Android device

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-wysihtml5

I've implemented bootstrap-wysihtml5 editor in one of my website. It works fine everywhere on desktop, iPad and on iphone, but doesn't display at all on Android device. I checked using Chrome browser.

Can anyone please let me know whats wrong there.

---

**Update:** On checking 'bootstrap-wysihtml5' from its default website http://www.w3masters.nl/bootstrap-wysihtml5/, found its also not working on Android device (checked on chrome and other android browsers).

Comment: I have just implemented summernote. Its working  great i have checked on Android ,web but not on Ipads though. https://github.com/summernote/summernote

Answer (score 0):

The development of WysiHTML5 went on to another website. Maybe the newest version will fix your problem.

[GitHub](https://github.com/Voog/wysihtml)